# Completely wrong output (colors) of free model after update to version 2.92

Tags: rendering

I'm completely new to Blender. I had used it years ago and tried now to open a free model that I downloaded from the Internet. At first it looked normally, but after an update to the current Blender version the rendered car is pink instead of orange and has an opaque layer on top of it. All I did was loading the .blend file and hitting F12.

Example image (from the website the model is from):
[image]

My result:
[image]

I also tried changing the render engine. I got a lemon yellow car with "Workbench" and a black car with "Cycles". I did the same on Windows 10, Ubuntu and MacOS, all at the lastest (LTS) version with the latest Updates. The Blender version I had installed before was 2.69 or so, I'm not 100% sure. Is there a setting I don't know, or are .blend files from former versions not compatible?

Comment: What version of blender are you using now (to open this)? Projects saved in old renderers (such as blender internal) may not display properly in newer (2.8+) versions of blender which use cycles and eevee renderers. Also, pink usually means its looking for an image texture that it can't find (missing texture/broken link, etc....)

Comment: The installed version is 2.92. So I guess I have to take that into account when downloading models. There is a "textures" folder with image files, but my Texture Properties panel doesn't contain anything.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett If you make it an answer I mark it as the solution. I don't assume there's any way to convert a blend file to wok with a new renderer.